# Why 'npm start' does not run the project in a browser with Node server.js at port :::3131 ? (JavaScript project)

Tags: node.js, npm, port, npm-start, json-server

I have a project written in JS around month ago. Since that time I didn't touch it.Now I wanna run the project again.

But when I type in Gitbash '**npm start**' it's not opening the project in a browser.

It stucks at: '**node server.js**' and doesn't go further.

Yesterday I had a problem with port 3131 where the project was deployed. I got information, the port was busy. So I used the 'netstat' command in CMD (windows) to find all open ports and then used 'taskkill' to terminate listening to port 3131.

But even after killing listening to that port, effect of 'npm start' was the same as today.

And it is happening with all my previous projects now. All of them where written during my online coding course in online coding School. I have finished it around a month ago.
**Can it influence somehow at the issue with port 3131? Maybe I should change the port?**

Important info: the project was deployed to Heroku, but couldn't work there. But even after deploying to Heroku 'npm start' was able to run project in the browser (a month ago).

BTW, 'npm run' looks like working fine, it runs all test etc.

---

**Here is my package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "fer-07-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.jsx .",
    "init-project": "npm install && npm-run-all init:*",
    "init:dirs": "mkdirp dist src/sass src/css src/vendor src/images src/js",
    "init:files": "touch README.md src/index.html src/sass/style.scss src/js/script.js",
    "init:gitignore": "curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/Node.gitignore -o .gitignore",
    "init:gitignore:custom": "echo \"dist\" >> .gitignore",
    "test": "npm-run-all test:*",
    "test:html": "globstar nu-html-checker dist/*.html",
    "test:js": "eslint src/js/ --fix",
    "test:scss": "stylelint src/sass/",
    "build": "npm-run-all build:* test",
    "build:clean": "mkdirp dist && rm -r dist && mkdirp dist",
    "build:copy": "copyfiles -a -u 1 -e \"**/sass/**/*\" -e \"**/.gitkeep\" \"src/**/*\" dist",
    "build:sass": "node-sass --output-style compact -o dist/css src/sass",
    "build:autoprefixer": "globstar autoprefixer-cli \"dist/css/*.css\"",
    "build-dev": "npm-run-all build-dev:sass build:autoprefixer",
    "build-dev:sass": "node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true -o dist/css src/sass",
    "server": "json-server --port 3131 --no-cors --delay 250 --watch dist/db/app.json",
    "watch": "npm-run-all build build-dev -p watch:* server",
    "watch:browsersync": "browser-sync start --server dist --files \"dist/**/*\" --ignore \"dist/db/**/*\"",
    "watch:sassprefixer": "onchange \"src/sass/**/*.scss\" -- npm run build-dev",
    "watch:copy": "onchange -e \"**/sass/**/*\" -e \"**/.gitkeep\" \"src/**/*\" -- copyfiles -a -u 1 {{changed}} dist"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "flatpickr": "^4.6.9",
    "json-server": "^0.16.3",
    "rangeslider-pure": "^0.4.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-cli": "^1.0.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
    "copyfiles": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint": "^5.14.1",
    "globstar": "^1.0.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "nu-html-checker": "^0.1.0",
    "onchange": "^5.2.0",
    "stylelint": "^9.10.1",
    "stylelint-scss": "^3.5.4"
  }
}
```

---

**AND server.js:**

```
/* global require, process */

const jsonServer = require('json-server');
const server = jsonServer.create();
const router = jsonServer.router('dist/db/app.json');
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults({
  static: 'dist',
  noCors: true
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 3131;

server.use(middlewares);
server.use(router);

server.listen(port);
```

**HERE IS AN ISSUE IN GITBASH WHEN STARTING ANOTHER PROJECT WITH 'YARN START'**

```
$ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.10
$ npm-run-all -p server:*
$ node server.js
$ webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3131
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1318:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1366:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1452:7)
    at Function.listen (C:\Users\kpych.LENOVO-KP\OneDrive\Pulpit\Nowy folder (4)\Project-12_Travel_agency\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kpych.LENOVO-KP\OneDrive\Pulpit\Nowy folder (4)\Project-12_Travel_agency\server.js:32:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1345:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -4091,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3131
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
ERROR: "server:api" exited with 1.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

[Gitbash npm start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjTRL.png)

Comment: `echo $PORT` what does this say in bash?

Comment: Hi, after terminated the listening to port 3131 in CMD, there is no error in gitbash.
It looks like that after typing: npm start

$ npm start

> fer-07-project@1.0.0 start X:\Kodilla\Project_10-piizeria77
> node server.js

Comment: But I have a second project, different from this above, which is using port 3131 as well. And here after typing 'yarn start' there is an error as follow:

Comment: Please take a look above to line:
HERE AN ISSUE IN GITBASH WHEN STARTING ANOTHER PROJECT WITH 'YARN START'

Comment: Your `package.json` does not have a `start` script, so `npm start` will do nothing.